# JAXB Validation error message

Tags: ajax, spring, jsf-2, jaxb

I am working upon a single page application wherein I am using JSF2, SPRING 2.5, JAXWS 2.0 webservice client, IBM Websphere App Server 8.5 .

Basically My page has a form with multiple combo boxes. User is free to select a value and submit the value for combo box. Each submit is an JSF 2 supported AJAX submit.

When i submit the form for the first time after server start, I get the following error message :

```
[07/05/13 15:40:11:914 IST] 0000007c SystemErr     R 19677396 [WebContainer : 4] INFO org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl - ignoreXmlConfiguration == true
```

When I analyzed more, I found the code of `org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl` class at : 
http://www.find-code.com/src/org.apache.bval/bval-jsr303/0.1-incubating/org/apache/bval/jsr303/ConfigurationImpl.java.html

The code present at above link is as following:

```
/** Check whether a validation.xml file exists and parses it with JAXB */ 

private void parseValidationXml() { 
 if (isIgnoreXmlConfiguration()) {
  log.info("ignoreXmlConfiguration == true"); 
 } 
 else {
  new ValidationParser(getProperties().get(Properties.VALIDATION_XML_PATH)) .processValidationConfig(this); 
 } }
```

I am creating the webservice client using IBM RSA 8.5 .
I even added a blank validation.xml to my project but i still got the same error message in logs. Can someone help me get rid of this message please ?

Comment: This is an "INFO" message. Why exactly do you think that this indicates an error? Does something not work as expected/intented?

Comment: I'm getting same message in WAS 8.5, jsf-primefaces webapp. In the first submit of the login page, this log is written and user is unable to login. After the second submit, the login process works as expected.